# MSSQLServer Logging Many Missing Stored Procedure Messages

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We deleted some stored procedures related to Query notification service since we are not using them anymore. After deleting the procs we are seeing the error log getting filled with messages like below.

How do we stop such errors.

> The activated proc '[dbo].[SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedure-1c5b775e-e036-4181-8336-ba86d97d763d]' running on queue 'DATABASE.dbo.SqlQueryNotificationService-1c5b775e-e036-4181-8336-ba86d97d763d' output the following:  'Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedure-1c5b775e-e036-4181-8336-ba86d97d763d'.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Run to get the name of the queue

```
 select * from sys.service_queues
```

Then run

```
DROP QUEUE queueName
```